# Assign 0 to Id to Null value

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me to assign the value of 0 if no records found for this Linq query. Currently I am returning null, But i need to assign 0 if it is null.

```
//Linq Query
var ideasQuery = from b in db.StarLive_StarIBox_Ideas.Where(b => b.UserId == userid)
                         select new IdeasDTO()
                         {
                             IdeaId = b.IdeaId,
                             Idea = b.Idea,
                             UserName = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.cLogName,
                             DatePosted = b.DatePosted.ToString(),
                             Problem = b.StarLive_StarIBox_Problems.Problems,
                             Department = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.nDeptID.ToString(),
                             LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes.Where
                             (l=>l.IdeaId==b.IdeaId && l.LikedBy==b.UserId).FirstOrDefault().LikeID


                    };

//DTO Class
public class IdeasDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int IdeaId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Idea { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DatePosted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Problem { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Likes { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Liked { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? LikeId { get; set; }
}
```

//Postman Response

```
{
        "IdeaId": 21,
        "UserName": "Gowthamb",
        "Idea": "This is an Idea",
        "DatePosted": "Feb 14 2019  3:19PM",
        "Problem": "Problem 1",
        "Likes": 0,
        "Liked": false,
        "Department": "1",
        "LikeId": null
    }
```

Please help

Comment: A possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972295/firstordefault-default-value-other-than-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
//Linq Query
var ideasQuery = from b in db.StarLive_StarIBox_Ideas.Where(b => b.UserId == userid)
                         select new IdeasDTO()
                         {
                             IdeaId = b.IdeaId,
                             Idea = b.Idea,
                             UserName = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.cLogName,
                             DatePosted = b.DatePosted.ToString(),
                             Problem = b.StarLive_StarIBox_Problems.Problems,
                             Department = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.nDeptID.ToString(),
                             LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes.Where
                             (l=>l.IdeaId==b.IdeaId && l.LikedBy==b.UserId).FirstOrDefault().LikeID


                    };
```

To this:

```
//Linq Query
var ideasQuery = from b in db.StarLive_StarIBox_Ideas.Where(b => b.UserId == userid)
                         select new IdeasDTO()
                         {
                             IdeaId = b.IdeaId,
                             Idea = b.Idea,
                             UserName = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.cLogName,
                             DatePosted = b.DatePosted.ToString(),
                             Problem = b.StarLive_StarIBox_Problems.Problems,
                             Department = b.StarLive_Sys_Users.nDeptID.ToString(),
                             LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes.Where
                             (l=>l.IdeaId==b.IdeaId && l.LikedBy==b.UserId).FirstOrDefault().LikeID ?? 0


                    };
```

Explanation:

`LikeID` is a `int?` it means that it is `nullable`.

the `??` operator, means that if the result is `null` it must assign the value on the right, which will be `0` in this case:

```
LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes.Where(l=>l.IdeaId==b.IdeaId && l.LikedBy==b.UserId).FirstOrDefault().LikeID ?? 0
```

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Comment: Infact that variable is int? and not int

Comment: {
        "IdeaId": 23,
        "UserName": "Gowthamb",
        "Idea": "tst",
        "DatePosted": "Feb 14 2019  5:02PM",
        "Problem": "Problem 1",
        "Likes": 0,
        "Liked": false,
        "Department": "1",
        "LikeId": 41
    }

Comment: above is a response with an Id

Comment: it returns this error Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Comment: This makes no sense, it means that your query always returns an integer, so you can't have null in results. How do you get those nulls?

Comment: Post StarLive_StarIBox_Likes class if you can

Comment: I made LikedId in StarLive_StarIBox_Likes class to accept null. Now it is working .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this
change `LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes`  to  `LikeId=b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes == null ? 0 : b.StarLive_StarIBox_Likes`